# Let the random point (X,Y) be uniformly distributed on the unit disc $D=\{(x,y):x^{2}+y^{2}<1\}$

Tags: probability-theory

Let the random point $(X,Y)$ be uniformly distributed on the unit disc $D=\{(x,y):x^{2}+y^{2}<1\}$. Show that the polar coordinates $R\in [0,1]$ and $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ of the point are independent.

Comment: To prove independency you need to show that

$$ P\left[R=r\wedge\Theta=\theta\right]=P\left[R=r\right]
   P\left[\Theta=\theta\right] $$

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27399/how-to-show-that-polar-coordinates-in-a-uniform-distribution-on-a-disk-are-indep

Answer (score 1):

The probability density function for $(X,Y)$, given its uniform distribution is
$$
    f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{1}{\pi} I(x^2+y^2 <1) 
$$
where $I$ stands for [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). Now consider a bounded function $\varphi(R) \phi(\Theta)$ and consider its expectation:
$$
   \mathbb{E}\left(\varphi(R) \phi(\Theta)\right) =  \int_D \varphi(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) \phi(\arctan(x,y)) f_{X,Y}(x,y) \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d}y
$$
Now perform the change of variables to the polar coordinates. If the expectation factors into the product of expectations $\mathbb{E}(\varphi(R)) \mathbb{E}(\phi(\Theta))$, this proves the independence.

Comment: The unit disk has area $\pi$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks, fixed it.